# Can't offset orgin of texture

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to change the offset of the player and it won't move at all I wasn't to set the origin to move so I can rotate the sprite at an offset and I can make texture rotate at the top of it so it can work as it does on the other side. You will see in my set origin where I attempt this but with no success

```
package com.mygdx.game.Sprites.weapons;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.mygdx.game.PlayScreen;
import com.mygdx.game.main;
import com.mygdx.game.Sprites.player.LArm;
import com.mygdx.game.Sprites.player.Player;


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class FireRifle extends Sprite {
    private static boolean xflip = false;
    private static boolean yflip = false;
    private static World world;
    //public static Body b2body;
    public FireRifle(PlayScreen screen){
        FireRifle.world = screen.getWorld();
        setRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("fire rifle.png")));
        setBounds(PlayScreen.larm.getX(),PlayScreen.larm.getY(), 8 / main.PPM, 19 / main.PPM);
    }
    public void update(float dt) {
        if(!Player.runningRight) {
            if(xflip == true) {
                flip(true, false);
                xflip = false;
            }
            if(yflip == false) {
                flip(false, true);
                yflip = true;
            }
            this.setPosition(PlayScreen.larm.getX(), PlayScreen.larm.getY());
        }
        if(Player.runningRight) {
            if(xflip == false) {
                flip(true, false);
                xflip = true;
            }
            this.setPosition(PlayScreen.larm.getX(), PlayScreen.larm.getY()+5/main.PPM);
            this.setOrigin(2, 2);
            //this.setPosition(
            //(float) (PlayScreen.larm.getX()-(Math.sin(LArm.b2body.getAngle())/60)),
            //(float) ((PlayScreen.larm.getY()+this.getWidth()/1.6)+(Math.cos(LArm.b2body.getAngle())/60))); 
            // have to use (Math.cos(LArm.b2body.getAngle())/7.25) with this now to get it to move on rotation thingy yea
        }
        this.setOrigin(PlayScreen.larm.getOriginX(), PlayScreen.larm.getOriginY());
        //this.setPosition(PlayScreen.larm.getX(), PlayScreen.larm.getY());
        this.setRotation(PlayScreen.larm.getRotation()+0);
        System.out.println("x fliped: " + this.isFlipX());
        System.out.println("y fliped: " + this.isFlipY());
    }

}
```